# Function Totality with IO

Tags: haskell

After reading over Prof. Yorgey's [lecture](http://cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/08-IO.html) on IO, is the following function considered to be total?

`Prelude> let f x = return $ error "44" :: IO Int`

I understand that a total function terminates and returns a value for every input.

However, since Haskell separates the evaluation and execution of `IO`, I'm not sure how totality applies to `f`.

Comment: I think you'd be hard pushed to find someone who'd argue that functions using `error` are ever total.

Comment: So, a function cannot be called total if, upon execution, it may throw a non-fatal exception?

Comment: If to be considered total a function must return a value, a function that throws along any execution path can't be considered total, since it won't return in that case.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Well, what about `g x = const 3 (error "44")`? I'd say nearly everyone would consider it total. (I know, I'm being stubborn here :-P) I would also be picky about what total means in a lazy context. Sometimes, one simply requires that the result is non bottom, with puzzling consequences like `h x = (undefined,undefined)` being total. Or `h x = 1:2:3:undefined` being total. Or the OP's `f` since e.g. ``f undefined `seq` ()`` returns `()`, hence by monotonicity `f` never returns bottom. Sometimes "total" means "no bottoms, no matter how far you dig inside".

Comment: @chi you're right, the issue is a little more complex than I made out; the word "total" has some subtly different meanings. Perhaps we should be talking about "strongly normalising" rather than "total"? Under a strict evaluation strategy `const 3 undefined` would throw.

Comment: If you regard the term `return undefined :: IO ()` as denoting the program which does nothing and yields the value `undefined`, then this is a total program - it always runs to completion, without error (e.g. `return undefined >> print ()`) - it is only by inspecting the value that one discovers that there is a bottom there. But, of course, one can only inspect the value with `>>=` - which produces a *new* `IO` program, which again, only represents a *computation* - not something containing a value ("There is no String “inside” an IO String").

Comment: This is a bit pedantic, but I would say `f` itself is total since it just gives back the same IO action for all inputs. That IO action, when run, gives back bottom. Note, though, that the error does *not* occur when the action is *just* run. The value given back must be inspected in some way. So this is a little different than an error occurring "in" an IO action (as it would if you ran an IO action that threw an error because, say, a handle was closed). It gives you back a "pure" value that is bottom. This leads to the error occurring (potentially, at least) in the non-IO portion of the code.

Comment: So, I'd say: 1) `f` is total since it just gives back the same IO action for every input 2) The value produced by running that IO action is always a bottom value, so the IO action always gives back a value that's not total when the action is run (and the value inspected).

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I think it's tricky as well. About "strongly normalizing".. I don't know. I wouldn't consider `fix (\f x -> if x<0 then 1 else f(x-1)) 24` as SN since I can unfold the fixed point infinitely many times, yet the resulting function always returns `1` (on any nonbottom input), so I'd say that is total. Ditto for `const 42 (fix id)` which has an infinite reduction but has a totally defined result. SN usually means that there are no infinite reductions. Maybe the "right" notion is something like: for any "good"(?) input, the function applied on that input is weakly normalizing.

Comment: As a matter of theory, it depends in exactly how we define "total" as the comments so far show. As a matter of practice, what we *want* from totality is that we can always use values together in the way we "expect" from their types without encountering errors. In real programs if you had an `f x :: IO Int` you would expect to be able to use it as an `IO` action producing an `Int`, but if you do your program will fail at runtime.

Comment: Looks like you figured out how to troll haskellers

Comment: @Ben You can never trust an IO type. Consider `fmap read getLine :: IO Int` The trouble is that `read` is not total. But can we demand that a total function must not mention a non-total one in its result? Then what about `f n = (n+) . read` Clearly, `f a` is not total, for any argument a. But does this mean `f` itself is also not total?

Comment: @Ingo I don't think IO or higher-order functions are really related to the heart of the issue. Is `f n = [undefined]` total? It always returns a non-bottom value, and I can write other total functions that inspect this value (with `length` or `null`). It really comes down to: are functions that can return non-bottom things containing bottom total or not? That's largely a matter of which definition we choose to assign "total".

Comment: @Ingo My point was that from a practical programmer's point of view a function that produces `return $ error 44` is clearly the **kind** of thing we're trying to avoid when we prefer total functions, because I have to know more than its type to know what I can safely do with it. The compiler won't help me catch mistakes as I change things around, I can't reliably pass it to other operations that take black-box functions unless I know *their* implementation, etc; all the usual pitfalls of partial functions apply to it, regardless of which theoretical definition of "total" we choose to adopt.

Comment: @Ben I absolutely agree with you that `return undefined` or any other values that contain bottom are undesirable. I tried to show that there are expressions that do not contain bottom themselves, but may be undefined when used in certain ways, so as not to fulfill the promise their type gives. Unfortunately, this is a general Haskell "feature". Hence I come to the conclusion that it would be unreasonable to demand that a total (Haskell) function would only return values that will keep their type's promise in any case.

Answer (score 2):

The function `f` is indeed total.
It returns, for any input, a value. Specifically, it produces every time the same value.

The value happens to be an IO action, that, when executed, will probably terminate the program, unless run in a context that can deal with the error. But this doesn't play a role, since merely applying `f` does not run the IO action.

Here is an example program that uses `f` :

```
main = putStrLn $ show $ length $ map (f$) [1,2,3]
```

and it should print

```
3
```

Comment: What if we used the `IO` representation: `data IO a = Return a | PutChar Char (IO a) | GetChar (Char -> IO a) | ...` .  Still total?

Comment: @luqui Sure, how would it be not total then? I'd say it would not be total if `Return` was strict, but it isn't as it stands.

Comment: Just checking your definition. To you total means not exactly bottom for any non-bottom argument. Or maybe for any fully defined argument?  Is `last . (0:)` total? (we can give it [1,2,undefined]` and it will be undefined).

Comment: @luqui The former. I guess you want to point out that the function in question introduces a "new" bottom that wasn't passed to it in the first place, so that it is not safe to use the result according to its type. I find that view legitimate, but still prefer the "minimalistic" view for systematic reasons. Consider `fmap read getLine :: IO Int` No bottom in it, and yet it may produce an undefined value depending of the input. This is to say, it is almost never guaranteed that a value of type `IO X`  will indeed produce an `X` when executed.